# How many hashes one needs in order to reverse engineer hash function?

Tags: hash

If I know the pattern of a hash string, particularly dllldlll or llldllld (d=digit, l=low case letter), is it possible to reverse engineer the hash function? If so, how many hashes ones needs to do so, and what tools would you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to design a hash function which output always has the pattern(s) in the question, but which will be computationally indistinguishable from a random function producing such pattern(s) to an attacker not holding a certain internal key. An example would be HMAC-SHA-512 with a secret key, followed by reformatting and truncation to match the pattern with a nearly even distribution.

For such hash function, what's attempted in the question is hopeless when observing the hash as a black box. Hence what's attempted can be anything from trivial to impossible, depending on the hash function, and the level of access one has to the internals of that hash function.

Comment: @Radim In fact any function can be mapped to that particular pattern, by simply enumerating each of the possible outputs to each permutation of the pattern. However, more to the point, all secure hash functions have high entropy (or randomness). What you are describing sounds less like a hash, and more like a binary<->text mapping scheme (like Hex or ASCII).

Comment: Thank you @fgrieu for you answer. I wonder, if one has a certain number of those hashes, can anything be learn about the hash? Maybe discover some relationship between consequent hashes?

Comment: Thank you @Aron for those additional comments. What if one has certain number of those hashes, can the entropy by evaluated and perhaps lead to the fact that it is more a mapping scheme?

Comment: @fgrieu may I ask if you could recommend me any literature or point me to a right direction where one can learn about hashes and their security?